# return type unknown for template classes

Tags: c++

I have created a matrix class and want to add two matrices of different data types. Like for int and double return type of matrice should be double. How can I do that???
This is my code

```
template<class X>
class Matrix
{
..........
........
template<class U>
Matrix<something> operator+(Matrix<U> &B)
{
if((typeid(a).before(typeid(B.a))))
Matrix<typeof(B.a)> res(1,1);
else
Matrix<typeof(a)> res(1,1);
}
```

What should be "something" here???

Also what should be done so that I can use "res" outside if else statement???

Comment: Something like [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle both those issues with <s>C++11's auto return type syntax</s> *the generous assistance of @DyP* :).

```
template<typename U>
Matrix <decltype(declval<X>()+declval<U>())> operator+(const Matrix<U> &B) const
{
    Matrix< decltype( declval<X>() + declval<U>() ) > res;

    // The rest...
}
```

With this syntax, your "something" will be the type C++ normally produces when the two template types are added.

Comment: @DyP It's C++11 trial-by-fire for me.  Would you recommend `declval<X>()` over what I've posted?

Comment: I thought about using `template < typename U > Matrix < decltype( declval<X>() + declval<U>() ) > operator+ (Matrix<U> const& p);`

Comment: i cant get it....i getting the following errors......./usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
inserter.cpp:201:20: error: ‘declval’ was not declared in this scope
inserter.cpp:201:33: error: ‘declval’ was not declared in this scope
inserter.cpp:201:45: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
inserter.cpp:201:46: error: template argument 1 is invalid

Comment: @TilakRajSingh It seems your browser doesn't support the newest standard.

Comment: @TilakRajSingh Include the header `<utility>` to use `std::declval` also.

Comment: @TilakRajSingh: You need to compile using the `-std=c++11` command-line option.

Comment: @TilakRajSingh `g++ -std=c++0x temp.cpp` works fine for me on 12.04 gcc 4.6.3

Comment: @TilakRajSingh You might want to wait with more complex template code until you understand the differences in C++ standards and how to add flags to your compiler.

Comment: @TilakRajSingh Sorry to hear that.  You are using the older C++03 standard, which should have been mentioned in the question.  I'm not confident whether it's most appropriate to *change the nature of a 40+ minute old question* or *post a new question about C++03*.  Don't do either just now.  Someone smarter than me will see this and make a recommendation.

Comment: @TilakRajSingh I tend to agree with Drew Dormann, since the solution is more complicated for C++03 and the answers here are valid and ok for C++11. I'd also say leave this question (maybe accept an answer) and ask another one tagged with `C++03` (that does not imply I'd consider myself smarter than Drew :D ) Sry for re-tagging this btw.. was more confusing than it helped

Comment: thanks alot guys it finally worked. Can somebody suggest me what to install on my machine so that i dont need to use this -std=c++0x???

Comment: @TilakRajSingh That's good news that it's working!  I would recommend adding that option to a build makefile or script so you don't have to think about it again.

Answer (score 4):

Try `common_type`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
    // ...

    template <typename U>    
    Matrix<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type>
    operator+(Matrix<U> const & rhs)
    {
        typedef typename std::common_type<T, U>::type R;

        Matrix<R> m;  // example
        // ...
        return m;
    }
};
```

Comment: its not working m getting the following errors /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
inserter.cpp:201:28: error: ‘common_type’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
inserter.cpp:201:39: error: expected template-argument before ‘<’ token
inserter.cpp:201:39: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token

Comment: @TilakRajSingh These features are C++11 features - either compile with `-std=c++0x` or use boost or ask for a C++03 solution :)

Comment: i am using g++ compiler in ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @TilakRajSingh: You need to pass `-std=c++0x` to the compiler.