# how to determine the data type of a template class passed as object to another class

Tags: c++

This is my code. How do I make `A::type` be `int` or `double` or whatever else is used to make instances of class `B`?

```
template<class X>
class A
{
typedef "*****" type
........
.....
......
}
template<class Y>
class B
{
......
.......
....
}
int main()
{
B<int> x;
A<B<int> > y;
.....
....
....
}
```

Comment: Is this your new version of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16226162/420683) or unrelated? Sry I'm confused

Comment: Can you be clearer? What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it.

```
template<class X>
class A
{
    typedef typename X::type type;
};

template<class Y>
class B
{
public:
    typedef Y type;
};
```

Comment: Of course, this will only work if `B` is actually used as the parameter when declaring instances of `A`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau well it will work if there's a type(def) named `type` in the template argument. Would partial specialization be any better?

Comment: @DyP Yes it would be better, if implemented like in [0x499602D2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/0x499602d2)'s answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct B
{
    typedef T type;
    // ...
};

template <typename> struct A { /* ... */ };


typedef B<int> MyB;

int main()
{
    MyB          x;
    A<MyB::type> y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help.

```
template <class T>
class B;

template <class T>
class A {
    public:
        typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
class A<B<T>> : public A<T> {};

template <class T> class B {};

int main()
{
    A<B<int>>::type x;
}
```

Comment: Can you really derive `A` from `A` like that?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure you can. It was done in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14589567/701092) as well.